# How can I color a multirow and multicolumns table?

Tags: tables, longtable

I have this table. I want to color the left column (the two cells with the word Template) of blue. Also I want to color the first row, all the cells from Lineal to Tesla of grey color, and if it is posible, the cells of the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 0.15... of other color. How can I do it? I am trying with  \colorcolumn but it doesn´t work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[margin=25mm,showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{3.6pt}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | *{16}{c |}}
\hline
\multirow{2}{14mm}{\textbf{Method\newline Function}} & \multirow{2}{*}{Lineal} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Pol, for grade} &     \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Gaussian, for deviation $\sigma$} & \multirow{2}{12mm}{\centering S\\ method} & \multirow{2}{*}{Line} & \multirow{2}{*}{Upload} & \multirow{2}{*}{Fourier} & \multirow{2}{*}{Marconi} & \multirow{2}{*}{Tesla} \\
\cline{3-11}
& & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & $0.15$ & $0.25$ & $0.5$ & $2$ & $3$ & & & & & &\\
\hline
Template & 57\% & 80\% & 92 & 89 & 89 & 94 & 97 & 97 & 94 & 92 & a & b & c & d & e & f \\
\hline
Template & 57\% & 80\% & 92 & 89 & 89 & 94 & 97 & 97 & 94 & 92 & a & b & c & d & e & f \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of `colortbl` and some changes in the multirow command you will get something like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[margin=25mm,showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{3.6pt}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | *{16}{c |}}
\hline
\rowcolor{gray} && \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Pol, for grade} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\cellcolor{gray}Gaussian, for deviation $\sigma$} &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\cline{3-11}
\rowcolor{gray} \multirow{-2}{14mm}{\textbf{Method\newline Function}} & \multirow{-2}{*}{Lineal} & \cellcolor{gray!40} 1 & \cellcolor{gray!40} 2 &\cellcolor{gray!40} 3 &\cellcolor{gray!40} 4 &\cellcolor{gray!40} $0.15$ & \cellcolor{gray!40}$0.25$ &\cellcolor{gray!40} $0.5$ & \cellcolor{gray!40}$2$ &\cellcolor{gray!40} $3$ & \multirow{-2}{12mm}{\centering S\\ method} & \multirow{-2}{*}{Line} & \multirow{-2}{*}{Upload} & \multirow{-2}{*}{Fourier} & \multirow{-2}{*}{Marconi} & \multirow{-2}{*}{Tesla}\\
\hline
\cellcolor{blue}Template & 57\% & 80\% & 92 & 89 & 89 & 94 & 97 & 97 & 94 & 92 & a & b & c & d & e & f \\
\hline
\cellcolor{blue}Template & 57\% & 80\% & 92 & 89 & 89 & 94 & 97 & 97 & 94 & 92 & a & b & c & d & e & f \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```